# Trying to find a formula in a pricing sheet

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the formula to calculate the price of a product when a certain hight & width are given. I have an excel sheet with what the answers should be.

I tried:

```
height * width = X

X * Y = price
```

When only incrementing the width or height i find the following pattern:
every 100 of height is a 1.9796 step.
every 100 of width is a 4.4492004 step.

So we can calculate the outer columns. as long as width or height is 600.

Who can help me solve this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What does Y mean?

Comment: With Y i mean the factor/number to get the price. For example 600 * 600 = 360000. 360000 * Y = 81,82. If i know Y i can, when i'm right, calculate all the prices.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Recompute the table, subtracting $81,92$ (written as $81.92$ where I'm from) from each cell.  The relationship should be a bit clearer.